# How to check if a variable in a session is declared?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to figure something out. I am using CodeIgniter and I am storing some information in the session so I can access it everywhere. I need to check if a variable has been already set, but the code I am using is not working (controller break apart)

This is how I store the data in the session:

`$this->session->set_userdata('myvalue', 'x');`

And this is how I am trying to check if the variable has been declared:

`if (isset($this->session->userdata('myvalue'))) //doesn't work`

In advance thanks for reading and replying ;)

BTW: I need this function, because if I know that the var hasn't been declared it means the session has expired and has been destroyed. So I want to forward the user to a view where I tell him he has been inactive for too long and has been automatically logged out, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to check if a specific value is set in CodeIgniter's sessions:

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('myvalue') ) {
    // The item 'myvalue' exists in the session
} else {
    // The item 'myvalue' does not exist in the session
}
```

---

This is how CodeIgniter's `userdata()` function works, in `system/libraries/Session.php`:

```
function userdata($item)
{
    return (!isset($this->userdata[$item])) ? FALSE : $this->userdata[$item];
}
```

If the item doesn't exist in the session, `FALSE` is returned, otherwise the item is.

Comment: Wooow, thank you for the quick response. I was overdoing it for some reason. I was doing this check the same way for a regular variable, dunno why I didn't use it for the session. Ill accept your answer in 5 mins ;)

Comment: The isset() on userdata() is not useless, is _wrong_ . You should be getting a proper error for that

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use function, `userdata()` already returns FALSE if the variable is not set, so:

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('myvalue')) {
   //code here
}
```

is enough.

`if (isset($this->session->userdata('myvalue')))` doesn't work because `isset()` can't use the return value of a function. You should get an E_NOTICE saying  that, though, something like

> can't use method return value in write context